# Mathematical Statistics (Poisson Distribution)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The number of defects $Y$ per yard in a certain fabric has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\Lambda$. The parameter $\Lambda$ is itself a random variable with density $f_{\Lambda}(\lambda)=\frac{\lambda}4 e^{-\lambda/2}$, $\lambda>0$. Thus we have
       $$P\{\,Y = k \mid \Lambda = \lambda\,\}=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}, \qquad k\ge 0$$ and $$\Lambda \sim f_{\Lambda}(\lambda)= \frac{\lambda}4 e^{-\lambda/2}, \qquad \lambda>0.$$
I have to find $E(Y)$ and $\mathop{\mathrm{var}}(Y)$.

So E(Y)=summation(from k=0 to infinity) kf_y(k) anf f_y(k)= Integral(from 0 to infinity) of f_y,Λ(k,λ)dλ, but is that the same as f_Λ(λ) because if I did that I would have 2 variables in  only a single variable?

I'm studying for the probability actuary exam and I'm having trouble with this topic, could someone walk me through the steps please.

Well what are the simpler approaches.

Comment: "I honestly have no idea where to even start here"... Honestly this is odd if you ever solved anything similar to the exercise (have you not?). To begin with, what is $E[Y\mid\Lambda=\lambda]$? Then, what is $E[Y\mid\Lambda]$? Then $E[Y]$...

Answer (score 0):

OK, there's a hint.
You have a conditional distribution of $Y$ given $\Lambda$, so the joint distribution of $Y$ and $\Lambda$ would be:
$$f_{Y,\Lambda}(k,\lambda)=f_{Y| \Lambda}( k | \lambda)\cdot f_{\Lambda}(\lambda)$$
and the marginal distribution of $Y$ would be
$$f_{Y}(k)=\int_{0}^\infty f_{Y,\Lambda}(k,\lambda)\; \mathrm  d\lambda$$
Then use the definition:
$$    \operatorname{E}[Y] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k\, f_Y(k),$$
$$\operatorname{Var}(X) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k - \operatorname{E}[Y])^2 f_Y(k)$$

Comment: Sure, this works in general, but here much simpler approaches exist.